# Code section as macro parameter

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For a debug purpose I defined the following macro

```
#define SECTION_TIME(out, s) GPIO_SetOut(out); \
                             s \
                             GPIO_ClrOut(out);
```

usage:

```
SECTION_TIME(GPIO_fooOut,
      foo();
      bar();
      foo=bar^foo;....;....;
)
```

Goal: needed to mesure time of some code. 
Sometimes this macro do not compile. Did I miss understand somthing?
PS: I also tried surrounding my code with {}

```
error: macro "SECTION_TIME" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 2
```

Comment: You'd probably be much better off writing a pair of `SETION_TIME_BEGIN` and `SECTION_TIME_END` macros, rather than trying to shoehorn arbitrary amounts of code into a macro param.

Comment: Run the preprocessor to observe the macro expansion (with ```cpp file.c``` for the GNU compiler)

Comment: Given example results in plausible code (i.e. looks like you might want it) for `gcc -E -P`. bash-3.1$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1 Does the example give you the error you describe?

Comment: Is using the `,` operator relevant difference between code which works and code which does not work? It makes the difference for my attempts to recreate your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch -E -P option fails I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I finally use two macros, I just want understand what happen when preprocessor expand my macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When code walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it better fully behave exactly like a duck. What I mean by that is that `SECTION_TIME(GPIO_fooOut, ...)` (sort of) looks like one statement while in reality it maps to 3 or more statements. This is bad, and you should strive to truely make it one statement.

This is actually not difficult, and the common idiom used for this is to wrap the macro content in `do { ... } while (0)` *without* a trailing semicolon (so that the trailing semicolon is supplied to the end of the macro invocation).

So you should at least change your macro to something like

```
#define SECTION_TIME(out, s) \
do { \
        GPIO_SetOut(out); \
        s; \
        GPIO_ClrOut(out); \
} while (0)
```

Also notice here that you should put the terminating semicolon for `s` in the macro and not the argument. So the macro should be invoked like

```
SECTION_TIME(GPIO_fooOut,
      foo();
      bar();
      foo=bar^foo;....;....
);
```

Depending on use cases, the suggestion to use SETION_TIME_BEGIN and SECTION_TIME_END might be a better solution.

Comment: I noticed when a code section start or contain a variable declaration, it crash the expansion macro.

Comment: I can  not see whay I should use semicolon after `s`, if my section is well written not need this?

Comment: Wrapping `s` inside an inner `do ... while` will allow for the code to contain variable declarations.

Comment: If you want to write (a) `MACRO(foo(); bar(););` or (b) `MACRO(foo(); bar());` is a matter of style, but if you write a macro that fails when invoked as (b) that is bad (which omitting the semicolon will result in). It fails the "Hard to misuse" principle of [good API design](http://www.cs.bc.edu/~muller/teaching/cs102/s06/lib/pdf/api-design.pdf). By all means watch [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw) as well. Yes, it is not short but it is well worth it.

Comment: You should in absolutely no way depend on "my section is well written". You should write robust code that will be easy to use (and not failing easily) by other people that does not know the inner details of the macro as well (and "other people" might just as well be yourself in the future...).

Answer (score 0):

Solved using variadic macro

```
#define BOARD_SECTION_TIME(out, ...)    do {              \
                                        GPIO_SetOut(out); \
                                        __VA_ARGS__       \
                                        GPIO_ClrOut(out); \
                                        } while(0)
```

Comment: So is the main reason for using this to solve the problem with `,` inside "s"? It looks like.

Comment: It was solved by using variadic, but I dont think that `,` was the main problem. Sometimes it works with

Answer (score 0):

I also use the way of `__VA_ARGS__` but I also make some curry-like syntax by defining a second macro, which name is in the first:

```
#define SECTION_TIME(out) \
    do { \
        /* remember to save the value, so that the same output is always cleared and can be used in the second one */ \
        decltype(out) _o = out; \
        GPIO_SetOut(_o); \
        SECTION_TIME_BLOCK1
#define SECTION_TIME_BLOCK1(...) \
        {__VA_ARGS__}; \
        GPIO_ClrOut(_o); \
    } while(0);
```

And it can be used like this:

```
SECTION_TIME(GPIO_fooOut) (
    foo();
    bar();
    foo=bar^foo;
    //....;....;
);
```

You see that the `out` input-parameter is a separate tuple and that the syntax is similar to the syntax of `if` for example, only the brackets are different. And if you want to define only one macro, you say that the code-parameter(s) should be in a tuple:

```
// this macro is only a help to remove the brackets and can be used in multiple definitions

#define PP_REMOVE_BRACKETS(...) __VA_ARGS__

/**
 *  \param code a tuple containing the code you want to run
**/
#define SECTION_TIME(out, code) \
    do { \
        /* remember to save the value, so that the same output is always cleared */ \
        decltype(out) _o = out; \
        GPIO_SetOut(_o); \
        {PP_REMOVE_BRACKETS code}; \
        GPIO_ClrOut(_o); \
    } while(0);
```

This can be used like this:

```
SECTION_TIME(GPIO_fooOut, (
    foo();
    bar();
    foo=bar^foo;
    //....;....;
));
```